# create an array with values of selected images

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to gather the images selected, take their values, put them into an array, and then push them to a mysql database.

Here is my current code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var startfind = $("body").find('.on').val();
  var awnsers = $('.on').map(function() {
    return $(startfind).text();
  }).get().join(',');
  $("img").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
  });
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert(awnsers);
  });
});
```

```css
#seasoning {
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.on {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/7HyU4yh.jpg" id="seasoning" value="0">
<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/OEHCjCK.jpg" id="seasoning" value="1">
<br>
<button>Submit</button>
```

I can't get the alert to show the values of the items selected.

Comment: You have two images with the same ID. IDs are supposed to be unique--otherwise they can't identify an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can trigger an event when you click on an image
2. Then listen on that event, an update the answer
3. use answer when you need it

an I change a little in your html code, that change img's value attr to data-value

============Here is the code and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91wbyws6/)=======================

```js
$(function(){
    //catch this values, because you will use these for more than one time
    var answers = [];
    
    function getAnswers(){
        answers = []; //empty old answers so you can update it
        $.map($('.on'), function(item){
            answers.push($(item).data('value'));
        });
    }
//init the answers in case you use it before click
getAnswers();

    
    $(document).on('click', 'img', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
        
        //trigger the state change when you click on an image
        $(document).trigger('state-change');
    });
    
    //get answers when event was triggered
    $(document).on('state-change', function(e){
        getAnswers();
    });
    
    $('#btn-show').click(function(){
        alert(answers.join(',') || 'nothing was selected');
    }); 
    
});
```

```css
#seasoning {
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.on {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/7HyU4yh.jpg" id="seasoning" data-value="0">
<br>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/OEHCjCK.jpg" id="seasoning" data-value="1">
<br>

<button id="btn-show">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code.

```
  $("img").on('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
        var awnsers = $('.on').map(function() { 
        return  $(this).attr('value');

  }).get().join(','); 
    alert(awnsers);

});
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/6ezf363a/